# Related rates problem.

Tags: calculus

This following question is from a schaum's exercise book.

Water is being withdrawn from a conical reservoir 3 ft in radius and 10 ft deep at 4 ft3/min. How fast is the surface falling when the depth of the water is 6 ft?
( Official answer is: 100/81π ft /min )

My answer is 24/6.48π ft /min.

Can anyone tell me why my answer is different?
( I do see numerous online answers for this same exact problem where they use Triangle Proportionality Theorem to solve this. I do not want to go down that route cause I did not come up with that way of solving this problem. This is the route that I thought of by myself, and would like to know why my answer is different. )

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you're wrong when you say "Since $\dfrac{dr}{dt}=0$." Look at the picture: As $h$ varies, $r=h\tan\theta$ varies as well. Indeed, since $\theta$ is constant, $\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \dfrac{dh}{dt}\tan\theta$. You should be able to go back and finish the problem correctly with this.

Comment: Your hint worked. ( Note to self: Always ask yourself if the quantity that you are dealing with is changing or if it is constant through out the problem ).

Comment: Indeed, when I taught related rates problems for decades, I encouraged my students to label their diagrams with variables and constants, putting constants only where they truly were constant. Then put to the side something like "when $t=0$, we have $r=3$ and $h=10$." By the way, please accept the answer when you are satisfied. And, if you are going to continue to participate on this site (which I hope you will), please learn to type up the content in MathJax rather than posting a photo. :)

Comment: Theta is constant in this problem. Thats why when we use the chain rule on r=htanθ to find dr/dt, the tanθ becomes zero during the chain rule process.

Comment: Of course, you don’t need $\theta$ at all. It’s just similar right triangles.